# %T specifier in printf option of `stat` command

Tags: bash-scripting, command-line-arguments, linux-device-driver, device-mapper

I want to know what is %T specifier in `stat` printf option and how it gets the file descriptor value ie., fd,**1** is printed by using the below command.

command is

```
$> echo `stat -L /dev/mapper/VolGroup-LogVol00 --printf="%T\n"`
```

ouput: `1` --> which relates to **"dm-1"**

Thanks in advance for any reply.

Comment: Please see [what is wrong with `echo \`stuff\``](https://superuser.com/q/1352850/432690).

Answer (score 1):

This format isn't defined by `bash`, but by [stat(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat).  Per the linked man page, `%T` gives the minor device type in hex.  I don't have your specific configuration, but, for example:

```
$ ls -l /dev/sda2
brw-rw-rw-  1 <user> <group>   8,   2 Oct  9 10:29 sda2
                               ^    ^
                               |    +-- minor device number
                               +------- major device number
$ stat /dev/sda2 --printf='%T\n'
2      <--- This matches the minor  ^ device number
$
```

If you `ls -lH /dev/mapper/VolGroup-LogVol00`, you should see `<something>, 1` in the output - `1` is the minor device number.

**Edit** to answer your additional questions:

"how %T specifier able to get that output": by calling the [stat(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) system call.  The `st_rdev` member of the resulting structure has the minor device number, which can be extracted with [minor(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/minor).  For use in your own scripts, just use `stat(1)` like you've been doing.

"what is the functionality of %T specifier in bash printf command": it is totally unrelated to devices.  Per the [bash hackers' wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf), it is the current time, formatted as for [strftime(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime).  The wiki gives an example:

```
$ printf 'This is week %(%U/%Y)T.\n'
This is week 52/2010.
```

Comment: the purpose of my question is how %T specifier able to get that output and what is the functionality of %T specifier in bash printf command